# How to use Setting's in overflow Icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I tried my level of best but I couldnt find it.I am working in navigation drawer activty where I can see a overflow Icon in top right when I click it, a Settings button like thing pops out when I click it(Settings) nothing happens

I dont no how to assing an XML to this so that when it is clicked a new activty should open

I know to create an xml and also to assign a onClickListner to the button but i am unable to proceed further since I dont no where to call the setting activty when that button(Settings button in overflow Icon) is pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSettingfActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

menu_main.xml -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: The code was simple and easy,satisfied my need and it works like a charm :) @Varundroid

Answer (score 2):

You can use find these below methods in activity and there you can inflate the menu and do want you want

Menu xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
     <item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

and you have to write the code like below in your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        case R.id.item2:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;           

        default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for providing extra details and ideas it worked..:)